# Jquery throw error : Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i have develop a small routine by `knockoutjs` for learning purpose. where i used `jquery` to have `FadeIN and FadeOut effect` which throwing error **Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element**

here is my  jsfiddle link **http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/60/**

please see my code and tell me what kind of mistake i did there and how to fix this error **Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element**

thanks

### here is the picture of the error

[image]

Comment: Working fine on Firefox.

Comment: enable firebug and then enable firebug console and test the code from jsfiddle link.

Comment: Unable to reproduce , here. `Window.getComputedStyle` not appear at http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/60/ ?

Comment: do u have firebug? if yes then u can produce the error.

Comment: @Mou Image difficult to view . This appear to be "error" `TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js
Line 6570`

Comment: stepping through the jquery code (the getComputedStyle call, specifically), it seems that `elem` is of type 'object', when it's expecting an Element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting latest version of `jQuery` for version 1.6.4

http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/67/

Comment: which version of jquery i should work with ? what is the latest version of jquery ?

Comment: can u tell me what will be the fix if i can not upgrade jquery file version?

Comment: @Mou See http://jquery.com/download/ , http://code.jquery.com/jquery/ . latest stable http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js , latest unstable http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.js  . If cannot adjust jQuery version , try debugging version 1.6.4 at lines  6560-6579.

Comment: i change the code and now used `if (element.nodeType === 1) 
{
  $(element).delay(1000).fadeOut();
}` which fix the issue. here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/gLfmztqj/69/ now fiddle is down.so check later the code. old jquery file version is working now. thanks for your help.